# Shell Script: Using files based on part of file name

Tags: shell

I have a directory (say ~/dir/) containing several hundred files. Half of these will begin with the string "ABC", ie they will be called ABC_0.csv, ABC_1.csv, ABC_2.csv etc etc.

My goal is to write a shell script that will take each of these "ABC" files and merge them together in one bigger file which I am calling "master_ABC".

I know how to merge them, but I do not know how to write a shell script that will only take files with names beginning in "ABC" (Note: There are other files in the ~/dir/ that I have no interest in and want to avoid).

Moreover, the number of "ABC" files will vary from day to day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture all the files in a list and then cat with append (>>) to master file

```
files=`ls ABC*csv`

 for f in $files
 do
   echo $f
   cat $f >> master_ABC.csv
 done
```

Answer (score 2):

Use wildcard `*` expansion to get different files `ABC_1.csv` and so on

`cat ABC_*.csv >  master_ABC.csv`

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard * for this.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat ~/dir/ABC*csv > master_ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ls` (or `find`) with `grep` in `while` loop:

```
ls | grep 'ABC_.*\.csv$' | while read fn ; do cat $fn >> master_ABC.csv ; done
```

or with `find` (especially if you need to traverse subdirectories recursively):

```
find . -type f -name 'ABC*.csv' | while read fn ; do cat $fn >> master_ABC.csv ; done
```

Note that `grep` accepts a regex, while `find` required a wildcard string.

I'd suggest to avoid using `*` in such cases as it will not work for very long list of files, and will also fail if any of the file names contain a space character.